# Good software to present beamer-generated pdf slide stack

Tags: pdf-viewer

I'm looking for a pdf reader that is well-suited for full-screen presentations of pdf files generated by latex beamer.

Acrobat Reader is not so bad, but I'd prefer something that can give highlighted mouse cursor options in full screen mode, sort of like powerpoint.

Before somebody suggests "Powerpoint", I won't use online converters because of privacy concerns, and locally installed options are quite old, or fairly expensive.

I have already tried converting by opening the pdf in Libreoffice Draw, and saving the odg.  Then I can open the odg in impress, and save it as an opt, but I'm not thrilled with some of the conversion artifacts, most commonly in equations.

Windows applications would be best, and a portable option would be super.